# header('Location:') its not working correctly

Tags: php, function, error-handling, output

Im trying to devellop a search system, and Im having a problem..

I have a index.php file and a search.php file in the same directory, and I want that When the user writes in the search field and submit I want to go to my search page.

But I dont understand what is happening because I go to this page: **localhost/project/tpl/search/** but everything is white, I dont have errors but is not showing the contet of my "search.php" file!

I alraedy tried with: `header('Location: http://localhost/project/tpl/search/');` But I have the same issue!

Somebody there knows what might be happening?

```
 <?php
        if(isset($_POST['search']))
        {
            $search = $_POST['s'];
            $search = setUri($search);
            header('http://localhost/project/tpl/search/');
            echo $search;
        }
        ?>
             <form  name="search" method="post" >
                <input id="test" type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search..." required="required" onfocus="if(this.placeholder == 'Search...') {this.placeholder=''}" onblur="if(this.placeholder == ''){this.placeholder ='Search...'}" />
                <input type="submit" class="expand" name="search"></button>
             </form>
```

I have my project folder inside htdocs, my project folder is this:

[image]

Then search.php is inside tpl folder, like this:

[image]

Comment: I suspect your `index.php` is overriding the `search.php` when you do `http://localhost/project/tpl/search/` . What is inside `index.php` anyway ?

Answer (score 5):

You forgot the `location` keyword on your `header()` function.

Must be..

```
header("location:http://localhost/project/tpl/search/");
```

**Warning** : Also, you are trying to `echo` content after the `header()` which will not be visible whatsoever..

Remove the `echo` and add an `exit` after your `header()` call..

```
if(isset($_POST['search']))
        {
            $search = $_POST['s'];
            $search = setUri($search);
            header('location : http://localhost/project/tpl/search/');
            //echo $search;
            exit;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks you are right, but I have in my code that right, I was writting here and I forgot that! So the problem its not only that :/

Comment: It seems that the location should point to search.php and not the search directory, per OP indicating his file is search.php and indicates nothing of a rewrite rule or anything

Comment: the problem is that even when I put my searh.php instead of /search/ the result is the same!

Comment: Yes I have rewriting enabled!

Comment: Can you post the contents of `search.php` ?

Comment: For now its just html Shankar Damodaran!

Comment: Maybe not even a search subfolder though? Looks like they should be in the root of tpl or perhaps even project, as tpl sounds like some sort of template subfolder. Just a guess. @OzzC what is the exact path of the search.php file (and the index file, just so we can verify)

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran You get `Headers already sent` when you output before setting a header not after.

Comment: Also, you both seem to have made the same typo in the comments here, `searh.php` versus `search.php` - - make sure that didn't end up in the code you are trying.

Comment: Thanks pinkflody, I update my question explaining where I have my files!

Answer (score 1):

Your `header` doesn't have the `location` keyword.

Comment: Thank you ikeMiguel, I already correct that error! But the problem still remains!

Comment: @OzzC You have several problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 header('Location: http://localhost/project/tpl/search/');
```